# sql, creating a late return date query

Tags: sql

Hi i'm trying to figure out how on how to create a query for a list of people renting a movie and returning it 3 days late or longer. I tested the query below and can't seem to pull out all of the data from my tables but only some of it.

```
Select * from USER U 
JOIN RENT R on U.userid = R.userid 
WHERE  R.ReturnDate - (SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) > 3
```

Comment: Why does GETDATE() have anything to do with the movie being late?   Isn't there a "DueDate" column?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? ("SQL" is just a query language, not a DBMS product)

Comment: @TabAlleman I am guessing maybe `ReturnDate` is due date, and query is to see if it is 3 days late right now.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * from USER U 
JOIN RENT R on U.userid = R.userid 
WHERE  R.ReturnDate > DATEADD(DAY, 3,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ReturnDate is due date and you are trying to find out if it is 3 or more days late today....

```
SELECT * 
FROM USER AS u 
INNER JOIN RENT AS r USING (user_id)
WHERE r.ReturnDate <= CURDATE()-INTERVAL 3 DAY
;
```

*...also assuming MySQL*